# Microsoft Visual FoxPro Pound, Hash, Hashtag, Number Sign

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Let's say I have:

```
SELECT 0
USE VALID_MEMBER        ALIAS "D1"          EXCLUSIVE
ZAP
APPEND FROM SUMMARY FOR D1.SUBFLAG # 'D'
```

What is the `#` sign's significance in the above statement?

I have not been able to find documentation.

**Edit:**
I think it may be the c# equivalent of `D1.SUBFLAG != 'D'` but have no idea if that's correct.

Comment: It's just "hash", not "hashtag". That's a Twitter thing.

Comment: Making it easier for others to find this if they end up in the same dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was correct. I edited some of our legacy code to find that `var1 # var2` is equal to modern day boolean expressions of `var1 != var2`

Comment: Yes it is just the same as != or <>. It has nothing to do with being modern or not. In math, be it years ago or today # is used for "not equal" (the more correct symbol is hard to type, else probably all languages would use that). You can use whichever you like.

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You are correct.  You can see it documented in the MSDN Visual FoxPro documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3b6st626(v=vs.80).aspx